# ¿Cómo diferenciar múltiples etiquetas creadas con un bucle en python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy creando etiquetas mediante un bucle que muestren información desde una base de datos, pero claro, como todas las etiquetas tienen el mismo nombre de variable sólo me muestra los datos de la última etiqueta que ha creado. He visto que se les puede asignar un nombre con "name", pero no sé muy bien cómo enviar la información...

```
for i in range(10):
    et = Label(marco, text = "Hola {}".format(i)).pack()
    et.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: prueba(i))

def prueba(num):
    print(num)
```

Pues eso, ¿cómo podría hacer para distinguir cada etiqueta? En tkinter, que no lo había dicho... gracias amigos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es que todas tengan el mismo "nombre" el problema es que en Python tanto las funciones/metodos normales como las lambda son evaluadas (el cuerpo) en tiempo de ejecución (late binding). Ésto hace que cuando se produce el evento y se ejecuta `lambda: prueba(i)` la variable `i` es evaluada **en ese momento** y en ese momento tiene el valor último asignado por el `for`, si es que no has reasignado después.

Además tienes otro error importante, muy pero que muy común:

```
et = Label(marco, text = "Hola {}".format(i)).pack()
                                             ^^^^^^^
                                             ^^^^^^^
```

**a `et` le asignas el retorno del método `pack`**, no el objeto `Label` que acabas instanciar. Es decir, `et` es `None` siempre. Luego realizas (o intentas) un `bind` a `None`....

Si necesitas una referencia al widget, no relalizes la llamada a `pack`/`grid`/`place` en la misma línea nunca:

```
et = Label(marco, text = "Hola {}".format(i))
et.pack()
```

Para resolver el primer problema tienes varias opciones.

### Pasar argumentos por defecto a la función lambda

```
import tkinter as tk


marco = tk.Tk()
marco.geometry("450x200")

for i in range(10):
    et = tk.Label(marco, text=f"Hola {i}")
    et.pack()
    et.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, num=i, label=et: prueba(event, num, label))

def prueba(event, num, label):
    print(event)
    print(num)
    print(label["text"])

marco.mainloop()
```

Los argumentos por defecto de una función son evaluados y asignados en tiempo de definición, no cuando se ejecuta como el cuerpo.

### Usar `functools.partial`

```
import functools
import tkinter as tk


marco = tk.Tk()
marco.geometry("450x200")

def prueba(num, label, event):
    print(event)
    print(num)
    print(label["text"])

for i in range(10):
    et = tk.Label(marco, text=f"Hola {i}")
    et.pack()
    et.bind("<Button-1>", functools.partial(prueba, i, et))

marco.mainloop()
```

### Usar el evento simplemente

Si solo quieres una referencia al `Label` en el que se ha hecho click, entonces no te compliques, usa el envento y su atributo `widget` sin más:

```
import tkinter as tk


marco = tk.Tk()
marco.geometry("450x200")


def prueba(event):
    label = event.widget
    print(label["text"])

for i in range(10):
    et = tk.Label(marco, text=f"Hola {i}")
    et.pack()
    et.bind("<Button-1>", prueba)


marco.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto. Aún estoy empezando en python, así que sepas que me he apuntado todo lo que me has dicho :)